# REST Assured send non UTF-8 character in the request

Tags: java, rest-assured

With REST Assured I want to create automation test, that sends non UTF-8 character in the request when Content-Type=application/json?

Using Postman it just works fine:

```
{
"billingAddress": {
        "address": ""
    }
}
```

, but with REST Assured it looks like this:

```
{
"billingAddress": {
        "address": "ð œŽ"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in your request the contentType `"UTF-8"` some thing like this

```java
.contentType("UTF-8")
.body(requestBody)
// some condition here
```